# Deriving MonadFree from a newtype with a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, free-monad, newtype, deriving

I’m trying to derive `MonadFree` from a `newtype` and I just can’t work it out. My current code is:

```
newtype ApplicationStack s r p m =
  ApplicationStack { runApplication :: StateT s (ReaderT r p) m }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s, MonadReader r)

deriving instance MonadFree f p => MonadFree f (ApplicationStack s r p)
```

and I get

```
• Could not deduce (transformers-0.5.5.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans
                      (ApplicationStack s r))
    arising from a use of ‘Control.Monad.Free.Class.$dmwrap’
  from the context: MonadFree f p
    bound by the instance declaration
    at src/Application/Commands/Base.hs:41:10-62
• In the expression:
    Control.Monad.Free.Class.$dmwrap @(f) @(ApplicationStack s r p)
  In an equation for ‘Control.Monad.Free.Class.wrap’:
      Control.Monad.Free.Class.wrap
        = Control.Monad.Free.Class.$dmwrap @(f) @(ApplicationStack s r p)
  In the instance declaration for
    ‘MonadFree f (ApplicationStack s r p)’
   |
41 | instance MonadFree f p => MonadFree f (ApplicationStack s r p)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `instance MonadFree f p ...` instead of `deriving instance ...`..

Comment: It's the same error either way.

Answer (score 0):

The [definition of MonadFree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) provides a default definition of `wrap`:

`wrap :: (m ~ t n, MonadTrans t, MonadFree f n, Functor f) => f (m a) -> m a`

GHC is trying to use this definition, but cannot find a `MonadTrans` instance.

You can define a `MonadTrans` instance for `ApplicationStack`, or you can guide GHC to base the `MonadFree` instance for `ApplicationStack` on the `MonadFree` instance for `StateT`, instead.  If you're using GHC 8.2 or newer, the easiest way to do the later is with [deriving strategies](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-strategies).  It looks something like

`deriving newtype instance MonadFree f p => MonadFree f (ApplicationStack s r p)`

With older GHC, it takes some fiddling to get the right extensions active in the right modules.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly I get the following when trying to derive MonadTrans "Can't make a derived instance of ‘MonadTrans (ApplicationStack s r)’ with the newtype strategy: cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough In the newtype declaration for ‘ApplicationStack’"

Comment: I would define the `MonadTrans` instance manually, not try to derive that.  Sorry that I wasn't clear about that in my answer.  I can't explain how GHC newtype deriving works in detail; I think I've just seen errors like that enough to accept that it won't work for newtypes that shuffle type parameters like this.